# MVC WEB Application Authorisation

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, authorization

I have inherited MVC web app that is at the current moment displaying all its views as public. The request is to make a single, admin page available to users that are registered with an app. I can tell that already existing registration page sends user info to an existing DB, but I would like to use that info when users try to get to admin page. As I said, the registration page, admin page, login page already exist but the question is how to modify the app so that admin pages require authorisation. Below is the current web config.

```
<system.web>    
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<authentication mode="None"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

Comment: Do you have roles set up in a DB table for users of this web app? E.g. Admin, Guest, etc. If you don't, you can follow this tutorial for MVC: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Answer (score 0):

You can set authorization directly with an `[Authorize]` role tag:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added [authorise] attribute and the debugger goes to db class and then just disposes, leaving me on the same page. How do I make sure that I redirect to the page I requested(that the method that you suggested is being called), The code practically skips the method with 'return view' if I add the attribute [authorise].

Comment: When you are NOT an Admin and call Index(), does your browser show a 401 Unauthorized error page?

Comment: HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: If I type in the credentials that are in DB I get the back to login page. DB does not hold the role, just the username password.

Comment: Roles should be explicitly defined in tables `AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUserRoles` and `AspNetUsers`. If users do not have roles, you will not be able to use `[Authorize]`. You will need to create roles to control page access as outlined in this tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97